# How to append to the dictionary?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary defined.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dataSource;
```

There is a function defined in such a way that this Dictionary will get filled atleast ones.

```
dataSource = l2ListText
             .Zip(l2ListValue, (lText, lValue) => new { lText, lValue })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.lValue, x => x.lText);
```

`l2ListText` and `l2ListValue` are `List<String>`
This filled in `datasource` dictionary serves as a datasource for a listbox.

And second time round, it checks if a listbox is empty, and when it is NOT empty, I want to append values to this `dataSource` and re-assign it as a datasource to the listbox again.

I am finding it difficult to achieve this, please help.

Comment: Have you tried `.Add` method of `Dictionary` class? after you add values to dictionary you need to explicitely rebind it to desired listbox

Comment: I have but somewhere I go wrong in the syntax and its giving me error that 'use of unassigned local variable' but infact following code works fine in `else` condition <br/>`Dictionary <string, string> datasource; <br/>if(lstbox.items.count>0)<br/>{<br/>//append here<br/>}<br/>else<br/>{<br/>datasource = l2ListText
             <br/>.Zip(l2ListValue, (lText, lValue) => new { lText, lValue })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.lValue, x => x.lText);}`

Comment: Are you going to append `l2ListValue` if a datasource already is populated?

Comment: Please share a code which you are trying and which is not compiling

Comment: @user1889838 `use of unassigned local variable` shows that you try to assign smth to 'null' collection. Be sure to check if `Dictionary` or any other collection is already initialized when you performadding

Comment: @user1889838 change you `if` condition to `if(datasource != null && lstbox.items.count>0)`. This wil ensure you have Dictionary initialized and that listbox isnt empty

Comment: @Nogard, ok that error is gone, thanks, But since I am using 'List<string>' in Dictionary I am not sure how to go about writing code for it so that it appends the full 'l2ListValue' and 'l2ListText' to the dictionary

Comment: What do you mean by `I am using 'List<string>' in Dictionary`? Do show some code!!!

Comment: @user1889838 from what you posted in question `Dictionary` is using plain strings both as Key and Value. You should not have any problems here. Please post your updated code.

Comment: This is the declaration 'Dictionary<string, string> dataSource;'  And the code to fill this dictionary is  'dataSource = l2ListText
             .Zip(l2ListValue, (lText, lValue) => new { lText, lValue })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.lValue, x => x.lText);'  Where 'l2ListValue' and 'l2ListText' are of 'List<string>' type

Comment: Dictionary<string, string> dataSource = null;
      if (lstbx_confiredLevel2List.Items.Count > 0)
      {
          dataSource.Add(l2ListValue[0], l2ListText[0]);
      }
      else
      {
            ataSource = l2ListText
             .Zip(l2ListValue, (lText, lValue) => new { lText, lValue })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.lValue, x => x.lText);

        }

            lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataSource = dataSource;
            lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataTextField = "Value";
            lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataValueField = "Key";
            lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataBind();

Comment: it gives me error in the code inside 'if' condition that 'object is not set to...'

Comment: please update your question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Main problem in your code is that you initialize `Dictionary` with each call. Thus, you will never achieve adding items, only populating it from `l2Lists`

This line `Dictionary<string, string> dataSource;` should be moved at class level to ensure you have same instance for each call to the method.

Modified code is below:

```
if (dataSource != null && lstbx_confiredLevel2List.Items.Count > 0) 
{ 
   dataSource.Add(l2ListValue[0], l2ListText[0]); 
} 
else { 
   dataSource = l2ListText .Zip(l2ListValue, (lText, lValue) => new { lText, lValue }) .ToDictionary(x => x.lValue, x => x.lText); 
} 
lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataSource = dataSource; 
lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataTextField = "Value"; 
lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataValueField = "Key"; 
lstbx_confiredLevel2List.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the LINQ `.Zip` extension, you can also do:

```
dataSource = new Dictionary<string, string>();
int zipCount = Math.Min(l2ListText.Count, l2ListValue.Count);

for (int idx = 0; idx < zipCount; ++idx)
    datasource.Add(l2ListValue[idx], l2ListText[idx]);
```

The `for` loop appends to your `Dictionary<,>`. If you run a similar `for` loop again, new values will be appended. Note that this will fail if the same "keys" (members from `l2ListValue`) are added again. If you want, you can overwrite existing members insted:

```
for (int idx = 0; idx < zipCount; ++idx)
    datasource[l2ListValue[idx]] = l2ListText[idx];
```